# Alamofire - not be code signed because its settings don't specify a development team in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode8

I hit the error on below on Xcode 8, can everyone help to solve it.
My application need to support iOS 8 and above.

Alamofire will not be code signed because its settings don't specify a development team.
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

What did it for me with the updated Alamofire and Xcode 8 is the following:

1) Open your project via the `<yourproject>.xcworkspace` file

2) Go to Pods -> Targets -> Alamofire -> Build Settings and set the following property:

[image]

I think it has to do with the fact that the new Alamofire 4.0 was a pretty big update due to Swift 3/Xcode 8. I haven't had the error before updating.

PS The first part *"Alamofire will not be code signed because its settings don't specify a development team."* of your error message seemed like a separate thing in my case, which either got solved because I did `pod install` a few times until Alamofire actually got updated or because of the setting that I mentioned above. Either way both things cleared out for me.

Comment: this fixed my issue too when I was trying to integrate a swift cocoapod in an obj c project

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the end of your Podfile to set the build configurations for each pod to use the latest version of Swift:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can we use `['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.1'` with Xcode 8.3.1 ?